# How to create mutable Tuple class?

Tags: c#, tuples

How do I properly inherit from `Tuple` and create `MutableTuple` class?
Let's say I've got something like `Tuple<StringBuilder, int>` and I want it to be mutable, so I can `get` and `set` its items.

In general it is probably not the best idea, but I need that for performance sake. Maybe there is an alternative way of how to pack two objects into one besides using `Tuple`...

Comment: Honstley: That should not be possible. Sure you could inherit from Tuple and define setters which return a new tuple, but that defeats your idea

Comment: it is better to create your own class, and customize it as you want

Comment: @ChristianSauer If I need to set the second item, should I then have something like `Tuple<StringBuilder, MyIntegerClass>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not do that. The `Tuple<>` class is designed to be immutable, so even if you *can* solve it using inheritance, you are going to be jumping through hoops to get what you wan't.

I'd recommend that to build your own class, you don't need the inheritance.

Now, to answer your actual question, in case you have a **really, really** good reason for needing the object to actually be a `Tuple<T1,T2>`, you can achieve it using reflection:

```
class MutableTuple<T1, T2> : Tuple<T1, T2>
{
    private static readonly FieldInfo FieldInfoItem1 = typeof (Tuple<T1, T2>).GetField("m_Item1", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    private static readonly FieldInfo FieldInfoItem2 = typeof (Tuple<T1, T2>).GetField("m_Item2", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

    public MutableTuple(T1 item1, T2 item2) : base(item1, item2)
    {
    }

    public void SetItem1(T1 item1)
    {
        FieldInfoItem1.SetValue(this, item1);
    }

    public void SetItem2(T2 item2)
    {
        FieldInfoItem2.SetValue(this, item2);
    }
}
```

Some important notes here:

- This is not guaranteed to work across framework versions, since it leverages private implementation details.
- It will probably be slower than creating new tuples (you mentioned a performance requirement), since you take a performance hit when doing reflection.

In short, don't use this code. Create  a new class if you need something that it mutable, and contains two items.